# Media queries don't work at all

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to make my wp blog mobile responsive, and for that reason I want to work with media queries in CSS. However, it doesn't work at all. As a proof of concept I just want to change the color to red, but nothing changes when I minimize the window. Please check my code snippets. I would appreciate it :)

First part:

```css
*/Conditional CSS*/

@media screen and(max-width : 900px) {
    body {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
<meta charset=="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,       
        maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  
<!-- css -->
```

Please note that the CSS is within the main CSS file and at the very end of the code. I am really desperate at this point.

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width : 900px) {
body {
    color: red;
}
}
```

If that doesn't work, try this one instead:

```
@media (max-width : 900px) {
body {
    color: red!important;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Andre, I tried to add the important tag but nothing changes.